# In itext7 - PdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages() returns only one page all the time

Tags: itext7

- I am trying to implement Page X of Y in footer part of html page.
- I am retrieving X by calling GetPageNumber(PdfPage) in PdfDocument and Y by calling GetNumberOfPages() in PdfDocument.
- PdfDocument is referenced from iText.Kernel.Pdf. But each time i am calling GetNumberOfPages(), it is returning only one page a t a time.
- Example : 
  When my total page is 4, I am getting footer value like below.
- 1st page -> Page 1 of 2
- 2nd page -> Page 2 of 3
- 3rd page -> Page 3 of 4
- 4th page -> Page 4 of 4

Comment: You are most likely using `PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE` to add y, correct? At the point that is called the document has the number of pages it says it has (at the start of the Nth page the document has N pages, but this changes each call). You have to add the total number of pages after the fact like in this example: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/converting-html-pdf/pdfhtml-header-and-footer-example#2908-pdfhtmlheaderandfooterexample.java

Comment: I am also using similar piece of code(in .net framework), but what i have observed is when the HandleEvent is fired, event has only two pages(it should have for pages).

Comment: Take a look at the example I linked again. In `handleEvent()` only "page x of" is written on each page as the document is created, and then after the document is complete `writeTotal()` is called to add "y".

Answer (score 0):

The link in the comment to the answer is no longer working, but I think [this](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/pdfhtml-header-and-footer-examples) is the updated link. I got it working with that information and a few minor tweaks.

Here's how I do it. Add an event handler like this:

```cs
pdfDocument.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, pageNumberHandler);
```

Here's my event handler code in C#:

```cs
using iText.Kernel.Events;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;
using NLog;

namespace PrintLibrary.iTextEvent
{
    public class PageNumberHandler : IEventHandler
    {
        private ILogger Logger => _logger ?? (_logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger());
        private readonly PdfFormXObject _totalPagesPlaceHolder = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0,40,20)); 
        public void HandleEvent(Event e)
        {
            var docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)e;
            var pdf = docEvent.GetDocument();
            var pageCount = pdf.GetNumberOfPages();
            if (pageCount <= 1)
            {
                // return here because I don't want page 1 of 1 printing, but only when it's more than 1 page
                Logger.Trace("Only 1 page in document, returning");
                return;
            }
            Logger.Trace($"Run {nameof(HandleEvent)}");
            
            var page = docEvent.GetPage();
            var currentPageNumber = pdf.GetPageNumber(page);
            
            var pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
            var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
            var canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pageSize);

            var p = new Paragraph()
                .Add($"Page {currentPageNumber}");

            Logger.Trace($"Printing text to page, current page # {currentPageNumber}");
            
            var x = pageSize.GetWidth() / 2;
            var y = pageSize.GetBottom() + 20; 
            canvas.ShowTextAligned(p,
                x, y, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
            canvas.Close();
            
            pdfCanvas.AddXObjectAt(_totalPagesPlaceHolder, x, y);
            pdfCanvas.Release();
        }

        public void WriteTotal(PdfDocument pdf)
        {
            var pages = pdf.GetNumberOfPages();
            if (pages <= 1) return;
            
            Logger.Trace($"Setting total number of pages on footer to {pages}");
            var canvas = new Canvas(_totalPagesPlaceHolder, pdf);
            canvas.ShowTextAligned($"of {pages}", 3f, 0, TextAlignment.LEFT);
            canvas.Close();
        }

        private ILogger _logger;
    }
}
```